# Adding a method to Restangular

Tags: angularjs, restangular

I am new to Restangular. Since its already been used in the project I am currently working on, I need to learn about it. I am trying to setup a new method, which upon called, calls a rest call and return nothing.

for ex: I have factory like this in

```
//app.js
    factory('events', ['Restangular', function (Restangular) {
        return Restangular.all('events');
```

I want to add a method ackAll by extending 'events'. I have tried like this.

```
RestangularProvider.extendModel('events', function(event) {
      event.ackAll = function() {};
      return event;
    });
```

I want to call this method whenever user login. I am not sure how to do that. Whatever i tried, i am getting error as "**ackAll is not a function** ". I am sure I am missing very easy part but I am not sure what it is.

Comment: The example in [Restangular docs](https://github.com/mgonto/restangular#adding-custom-methods-to-models) show to use `Restangular.extendModel` rather than `RestangularProvider.extendModel`.  Under the configuration section, it does list several methods that work with either `Restangular` or `RestangularProvider`, but `extendModel` is not listed there (although the `addElementTransformer` method is.)

Comment: thanks for the reply. I can see in my project that, they have used both addElementTransformer and  extendModel on RestangularProvider. 
And the point I am stuck is, in the Example of Restangular, they have user 'account' to call 'PrettyfyAmount' method which they have passed. I just want to call event.ackAll(). I am not sure if its even possible.

Comment: you want to call event.ackAll() as soon as it is loaded?

Comment: ya you can say like that.. I just want this to be called as soon as user login is successful. So ideally this method will be called first.